# Escape HTML in Languages with Accented Letters

Tags: java, html-escape-characters

Which html escape method in Java is recommended to use if I don't want it to escape accented characters, for example, in string "Matías", accented í should remain unescaped.

Both StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml() and Springs's HtmlUtils.htmlEscape() escape these letters.

Answer (score 4):

Using Spring's [`htmlEscape(String input, String encoding)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/HtmlUtils.html#htmlEscapeDecimal-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) you can pass an encoding like ["UTF-8"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html?is-external=true). According to the JavaDoc the characters won't be escaped if they're in the given encoding (or at least that's how I understand it).

Answer (score 2):

Guava's HtmlEscapers.htmlEscaper().escape(inputString) did the trick without specifying encoding

Answer (score 1):

Using Apache commons-text:

```
   public static final CharSequenceTranslator ESCAPE_CUSTOM =
         new AggregateTranslator(
                 new LookupTranslator(EntityArrays.BASIC_ESCAPE),
                 new LookupTranslator(EntityArrays.HTML40_EXTENDED_ESCAPE)
         );
   ESCAPE_CUSTOM.translate(input);
```