# Java StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4 as regular text

Tags: java, html-escape-characters, accent-sensitive

My target is to display special letters of message as regular text after using `StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4`.
Text example:

```
<html>
<body>
<p>éô</p>
</body>
</html>
```

My expected result is to make all the HTML tags being escaped, but not the text, that is here: éô

Code example:

```
String original = "<html><head><\\head><>éô";
System.out.println("original: " + original);

String translated = StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4(original);
System.out.println("translated: " + translated);
```

Output:

```
original: <html><head><\head><body>éô
translated: &lt;html&gt;&lt;head&gt;&lt;\head&gt;&lt;body&gt;&eacute;&ocirc;
```

I am expect to get:
`&lt;html&gt;&lt;head&gt;&lt;\head&gt;&lt;body&gt;éô`

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect from 'escapeHtml4' - what are you hoping to get? `"\u00E9\u00F4"` ?

Comment: I'm still a little bewildered. If you want those characters left unescaped then why pass them into the method? That should be a forward slash btw

Comment: I an passing a full message that can contain html and when showing the message as plain text I want to show these letters as is

Comment: So when the message is being viewed, do you want the user to see `&lt;` or `<`?

Comment: The HTML tags will be escaped, special characters will be displayed

Comment: Sorry I don't understand that. Please answer directly my last question - it's *binary*

Comment: I want to keep the text and make escaping on html related characters. For example I want to keep the French letters and not to make escape on it

Comment: I edited the question, it is should be clear now, anyway already found the solution, also posted

Comment: I'm glad you got it fixed but you never did answer my binary question

Comment: for this one: So when the message is being viewed, do you want the user to see &lt; or <?
The answer is &lt;
And for éô the user will see éô

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that I found the solution that mentioned here:
[Escape HTML in Languages with Accented Letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41105674/escape-html-in-languages-with-accented-letters)

by creating a custom escaping method that will use only two lookup translators:

```
public static final CharSequenceTranslator ESCAPE_HTML4_CUSTOM =
        new AggregateTranslator(
                new LookupTranslator(EntityArrays.BASIC_ESCAPE()),
                new LookupTranslator(EntityArrays.HTML40_EXTENDED_ESCAPE())
        );
```

In the original method `StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4` there are:

```
    public static final CharSequenceTranslator ESCAPE_HTML4 = 
    new AggregateTranslator(
        new LookupTranslator(EntityArrays.BASIC_ESCAPE()),
        new LookupTranslator(EntityArrays.ISO8859_1_ESCAPE()),
        new LookupTranslator(EntityArrays.HTML40_EXTENDED_ESCAPE())
    );
```